# Repetição básica em Python - dúvida em "and" e "or"

Tags: python, for, range

Estou aprendendo Python. Surgiu uma dúvida em um exercício de repetição (for).
O exercício é identificar todos os números ímpares e ao mesmo tempo múltiplos de 3, no intervalo de 0 a 500.

A solução que inicialmente criei foi pular de 3 em 3, assim identificando os múltiplos de 3. E posteriormente identificar os números diferentes de pares (que terminavam em: 0, 2, 4, 6 e 8) para restar somente os ímpares:

```
for c in range(0, 501, 3):
    c = str(c)
    if c[-1] != str(0) or c[-1] != str(2) or c[-1] != str(4) or c[-1] != str(6) or c[-1] != str(8):
        print(c)
```

Porém, notei que utilizando "or" não funcionou. Somente substituindo por "and" funcionou. Mas não entendi essa lógica.

Na minha leitura ficaria: se o último dígito não terminar com 0 ou 2 ou 4 ou 6 ou 8, então print.
Mas só funcionou utilizando: se o último dígito não terminar com 0 e 2 e 4 e 6 e 8, então print:

```
for c in range(0, 501, 3):
    c = str(c)
    if c[-1] != str(0) and c[-1] != str(2) and c[-1] != str(4) and c[-1] != str(6) and c[-1] != str(8):
        print(c)
```

Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo de usar "and" e não "or"? Sei que tem outras formas de resolver, mas preciso entender isso.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 5):

O `or` indica que se qualquer uma das condições for verdadeira, já é o suficiente. Por exemplo, se o último dígito for 2, a primeira condição (que testa se é diferente de zero) é verdadeira e ele já entra no `if`.

Com `and`, todas as condições devem ser verdadeiras. Ou seja, o número deve ser diferente de zero **e  também** diferente de 2, e diferente de 4, etc. Por isso só funciona com `and`.

---

Dito isso, uma forma mais simples é começar do 3, e pular de 6 em 6, assim você sempre cairá em um múltiplo de 3 que também é ímpar:

```
for i in range(3, 501, 6):
    print(i)
```

Claro que, se quiser testar todos os múltiplos de 3, use o resto da divisão por 2 para saber se é ímpar (não precisa converter o número para string):

```
for i in range(0, 501, 3):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        print(i)
```

Ou seja, se o resto da divisão por 2 é diferente de zero, é porque o número é ímpar.

Answer (score 3):

Complementando o que já foi dito, o operador lógico `or` retorna `True` bastando uma de suas premissas ser verdadeira e o operador lógico `and` retorna `True` apenas quando ambas as premissas forem verdadeiras, aqui estão as descrições e tabelas verdades [dos operadores lógicos em python](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), mais algumas operações lógicas triviais usadas em linguagem de programação:

**Conjunção(AND)**:
O operador lógico `and`, aplicada a dois operandos e retorna a constante lógica [`True`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/constants.html#True) caso ambos os operandos sejam verdadeiros.

| a | b | a and b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True |
| True | False | False |
| False | True | False |
| False | False | False |

**Disjunção(OR)**:
O operador lógico `or`, aplicada a dois operandos e somente retorna a constante lógica `True` caso um os operandos sejam verdadeiros.

| a | b | a or b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True |
| True | False | True |
| False | True | True |
| False | False | False |

**Negação(NOT)**:
O operador lógico `not`, aplicada a apenas um operando e retorna a constante lógica contrária ao valor lógico do operando.

| a | not a |
| --- | --- |
| True | False |
| False | True |

**Disjunção exclusiva(XOR)**:
Não possui equivalente direto em python.
Pode ser realizada por meio da expressão `(a and not b) or (not a and b)`, aplicada a dois operandos e somente retorna a constante lógica `True` quando os operando não são iguais.

| a | b | (a and not b) or (not a and b) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | False |
| True | False | True |
| False | True | True |
| False | False | False |

**Negação disjuntiva(NOR)**:
Não possui equivalente direto em python.
É realizada por meio da expressão `not(a or b)`, aplicada a dois operandos e somente retorna a constante lógica `True` quando os operando são [`False`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/constants.html#False).

| a | b | not(a or b) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | False |
| True | False | False |
| False | True | False |
| False | False | True |