# Problema onde o IF e ELIF não funcionam em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Primeira vez programando, comecei há uma semana e decedi tentar algo. Porém, eu estou com um problema onde, não importa o que eu coloque na váriavel, ela sempre mostra o mesmo resultado, que no caso é :"**StreamShop, R$89,99**".
Já tentei definir o tipo da váriavel para str, re-escrever todo o código, diminuir a quantidade de caracteres, nada funcionou. Estou usando o Colab da google para programar.

```
x = input("Diga-me a estação que deseja fazer a compra: \n")

if x.lower() == "verão" or "verao":
  print("StreamShop,","R$89,99")

elif x.lower() == "primavera":
  print("Loajing,", "R$84,00")

elif x.lower() == "outono":
  print("Showpping,", "R$73,00")

elif x.lower() == "inverno":
  print("Loajing,", "R$139,00")

else:
  print("Valor inválido")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Problema:

O fluxo do seu código sempre cairá em `print("StreamShop,","R$89,99")`. Isso porque na linha...

```
if x.lower() == "verão" or "verao":
```

...está sendo instruindo ao programa a realizar a seguinte sequencia de operações:

- `x.lower() == "verão"` uma operação para comparar a igualdade entre dois valores cujo o resultado poderá retornar `True` ou `False` dependendo do valor de `x.lower()` ser igual ou não a string `verão`. O que implica em duas possíveis expansões para expressões:
- `True or bool("verao")` no caso de `x.lower() == "verão"` resultar `True`.
- `False or bool("verao")` no caso de `x.lower() == "verão"` resultar `False`.

Porém como visto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490461/repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-b%C3%A1sica-em-python-d%C3%BAvida-em-and-e-or/490473#) o operador lógico `or` retorna `True` bastando uma de suas premissas ser verdadeira, então em `True or bool("verao")` o interpretador automaticamente prossegue expandindo a expressão para apenas `True` assim ignorando a parte expressão da expressão `or bool("verao")` pois seu resultado é irrelevante.
Já em `False or bool("verao")` o interpretador converte `bool("verao")` em `True` usando o [procedimento de teste de verdade](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth), assim ignorando a parte expressão da expressão `False or` pois seu resultado é irrelevante.

Então não importado o valor de `x.lower()` pois `x.lower() == "verão" or "verao"` sempre será `True` e o fluxo do seu código sempre cairá em `print("StreamShop,","R$89,99")`.

## Solução 1:

Um reparo imediato no seu código seria na primeira comparação testar se `x.lower()` está contido no [conjunto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) de palavras `{"verão", "verao"}` utilizando o operador [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
x = input("Diga-me a estação que deseja fazer a compra: \n").lower()

if x in {"verão", "verao"}:
  print("StreamShop,","R$89,99")    
elif x == "primavera":
  print("Loajing,", "R$84,00")    
elif x == "outono":
  print("Showpping,", "R$73,00")    
elif x == "inverno":
  print("Loajing,", "R$139,00")    
else:
  print("Valor inválido")
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/PrimaveraVerao1)</sup>

## Solução 2:

Pessoal mais idoso costumam escrever *primavéra*, *verão*, *outôno* e *invérno*, então outra possibilidade de reparo seria remover toda a acentuação da entrada utilizando o método [`unicodedata.normalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) para obter o [equivalente unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) da entrada utilizando a forma de normalização de compatibilidade e de composição(NFKD) que basicamente modifica a representação de caracteres unicode acentuados em seus equivalente conjugados sem alterar a representação visual do caractere, seja a palavra *verão*, continuaria sendo exibida como *verão* porém o caractere *ã* é decomposto no conjugado *a* + *~*. Então a seguir é feita uma conversão dessa string normalizada com o método [str.encode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) em ASCII para remover o conjugado, no caso os acentos, e finalmete com o método [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) e retornada a string UTF8 sem a acentuação e caracteres especiais:

```
import unicodedata

x = input("Diga-me a estação que deseja fazer a compra: \n").lower()

x = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf8')

if x == "verao":
  print("StreamShop,","R$89,99")    
elif x == "primavera":
  print("Loajing,", "R$84,00")    
elif x == "outono":
  print("Showpping,", "R$73,00")    
elif x == "inverno":
  print("Loajing,", "R$139,00")    
else:
  print("Valor inválido")
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Rep.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/PrimaveraVerao2)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

O problema do seu programa é na segunda condição do if. Vou dividir esse if em 2 para você perceber:

Original:

```
if x.lower() == "verão" or "verao":
```

Dividido:

```
if x.lower() == "verão":

if "verao":
```

Repare que no primeiro if a palavra verão é comparada com a variável x, mas no segundo if isso não ocorre e isso gera o erro lógico. Para o segundo if funcionar como o esperado precisaríamos deixar:

```
if x.lower() == "verao":
```

Então o if seria assim:

```
if x.lower() == "verão" or x.lower() == "verao":
```

O motivo do primeiro if ser ativado é que por padrão qualquer coisa que seja diferente de zero é considerada verdade.
Você pode testar os seguintes if e ver que só o do zero que não será ativado:

```
if 0: print('Não ativou')

if 1: print('Ativou')

if "Isso é diferente de zero": print('Ativou')

if 'Isso também': print('Ativou')

if 'verao': print('Ativou')
```

Answer (score 2):

Pude notar que você poderia otimizar seu código colocando as funções de tratamento de **string** na sequência das mesmas, portanto, se você puder verificar, me dei a liberdade de adicionar uma simples função que destravou seu problema.

A finalidade desta função **.replace()**, tem como objetivo principal fazer a troca de uma determinada parte da sua string para uma outra que você preferir, otimizando assim a resposta assertiva do usuário final.

```py
x = input("Diga-me a estação que deseja fazer a compra - evite acentuação, "
          "por gentileza: \n").lower().replace('verão', 'verao')

if x == "verao":
    print("StreamShop,", "R$89,99")

elif x == "primavera":
    print("Loajing,", "R$84,00")

elif x == "outono":
    print("Showpping,", "R$73,00")

elif x == "inverno":
    print("Loajing,", "R$139,00")

else:
    print("Valor inválido")
```