# confuso com operador and e or, laço não finaliza

Tags: python, python-3.x

quando `parada` recebe `N` ou o `S`, o laço não finaliza.

```
parada = str(input('ADICIONNAR MAIS ALGUÉM?: [S/N]')).upper()
    while parada not in 'S' or 'N':
        parada = str(input('>>>APENAS S OU N<<<\nADICIONNAR MAIS ALGUÉM?: [S/N]').upper())
    if parada == 'N':
        break
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Problema onde o IF e ELIF não funcionam em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/490685/problema-onde-o-if-e-elif-n%c3%a3o-funcionam-em-python)

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza o `or`, está comparando duas condições. Assim, a forma mais correta de fazer isso seria substituir o `while parada not in 'S' or 'N':` por:

```
while parada not in ('N', 'S'):
```

*ou*

```
while parada != 'N' or parada != 'S':
```

*ou ainda*

```
while parada not in 'N' or parada not in 'S':
```

Segue o código:

```
parada = str(input('ADICIONNAR MAIS ALGUÉM?: [S/N]')).upper()
while parada not in ('S', 'N'):
    parada = str(input('>>>APENAS S OU N<<<\nADICIONNAR MAIS ALGUÉM?: [S/N]').upper())
    if parada == 'N':
        break
```